# Not understanding why equation 2 and equation 3 has to be multiplied with $v(x)$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, differential-operators

The discrete differential operator $L_h$ is defined as: 
$(L_h v)(x_j)=-\frac{v(x_{j+1})-2v(x_j)+v(x_{j-1})}{\Delta x^2}$ (Equation 1). The contineous problem had solution $v(x_j)=sin(\beta x_j)$. It is therefore tested if this is also a solution to the discrete case. The expression for $v(x_j)$ is then inserted into the equation for $(L_h v)(x_j)$ as follows below:
$L_h u=\frac{-sin(\beta x_j +\beta \Delta x)+2sin(\beta x_j)-sin(\beta x_j -\Delta x)}{\Delta x^2}v(x)$ (Equation 2). 
By using the two trigonometric identities below, this can expression can be changed to Equation 3:

$1-cos(y)=2sin^2(\frac{y}{2})$

$sin(x+y)+sin(x-y)=2cos(y)sin(x)$

$L_h u=  \left.\frac{-2cos(\beta \Delta x)sin(\beta x_j)+2sin(\beta x_j)}{\Delta x^2}v(x)\right\vert \cdot \frac{1}{sin(\beta x_j)}$

$L_h u=\frac{2-2cos(\beta \Delta x)}{\Delta x^2}v(x)=\frac{2}{\Delta x^2}[1-cos(\beta \Delta x)]v(x)$ (Equation 3)

My book goes from equation 1 to 3, without showing the steps between, but I believe the steps I have made between is correct when equation 3 is correct. My problem is that I do not understand why equation 2 and 3 has to contain a $v(x)$ multiplied on the right side of the equal sign. In my mind, equation 2 and 3 are equal to $(Equation1*v(x)) $. Does anyone understand why equation 2 and three has to contain $v(x)$ multiplied with the fraction in front of it?
David

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the $v(x)$ in equation 2 should have been there. You only want to see that (actually, $v(x_j)$) at the end. In other words you should get

$$\frac{-\sin(\beta x_j + \beta \Delta x) + 2 \sin(\beta x_j) - \sin(\beta x_j - \beta \Delta x)}{\Delta x^2} = C \sin(\beta x_j)$$

for some $C$ independent of $j$, for $j=2,\dots,N-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is the same result I get. Do you understand why equation 3 has to be multiplied by $v(x)$ in order to get equation 1? My book goes directly from equation 1 to equation 3, but I do not understand how it can be correct that we have to multiply equation 3 with $v(x)$.

Comment: I agree, it seems to me that equations 2 and 3 contain an extraneous factor of $v(x)$.

Comment: Okay. Thank your for taking the time to check the equations.